# Get upper element from DIV tree in HTML Structure

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-tag-manager

I have HTML code for every widget like this:

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxScM.png)

How get name attribute of **div data-tracker-id** (=118DBA90ECB84E7BB9E7C07402F4B4B25CC0CD43818B92F8E0C26CA63C5F543D) when i'm clicking on **class**, for instance, "slick-arrow slick-prev"? Making DOM Element with CSS-Selector doesn't work.

Comment: Your example code doesn't have a name attribute

Comment: And how to get this data (=118DBA90ECB84E7BB9E7C07402F4B4B25CC0CD43818B92F8E0C26CA63C5F543D) ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom HTML tag for this, where you can write your own code, which looks up this information, relative to the clicked element, which can be referred as {{Click Element}}, when enabled within built-in variables.

You can do it using jQuery, with the [parent() function](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), which traverses up to the specified parent element. E.g.

```
var parent = $({{Click Element}}).parent('div[data-tracker-id]');
```

You can also simulate this functionality using vanilla JavaScript. One possible solution:

```
    //define function
      var gtmGetClosest = function ( elem, selector ) {

        // Element.matches() polyfill
        if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
            Element.prototype.matches =
                Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
                Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
                Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
                Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
                Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
                function(s) {
                    var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                        i = matches.length;
                    while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
                    return i > -1;
                };
        }

        // Get closest match
        for ( ; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode ) {
            if ( elem.matches( selector ) ) return elem;
        }

        return null;

      };

    //use it
    var parent = gtmGetClosest({{Click Element}}, 'div[data-tracker-id]');
```

Custom function was based on [this article](https://gomakethings.com/climbing-up-and-down-the-dom-tree-with-vanilla-javascript/).

Comment: Thanks! But how to use second code (with Vanilla JS)? Create 2 JS-variables (gtmGetClosest and parent) in GTM or how?

Comment: There are several solutions. The quick and dirty way is to include it in the same custom HTML tag, but it will re-initialize the function every time the tag runs. You can put it in a separate Custom HTML, and use it as a setup tag, but limited to run once per page. Or you can define a variable, that returns a function. More tips on this: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/create-utility-variables-returning-functions/